# SQLITE get generated column type

Tags: sqlite

After creating an sqlite table with a generated column in it, the type only shows up, if it was specified, and there can be cases when junk gets into the type description as well.

Example:

```
create table test(
    id integer primary key not null, 
    gen generated always as (id * 2) stored
);
```

Using `pragma table_xinfo(test);` afterwards nets the following output:

```
0|id|INTEGER|1||1|0
1|gen||0||0|3
```

The type is simply missing from the correct column.

If the column were to be created with:

```
gen integer generated always as (id * 2) stored
```

instead, then the type would correctly show up as INTEGER.

Are there any methods that would get the type of a column in a table without having to resort to parsing the table creation code?

Comment: `pragma table_xinfo(test);` returns `'generated always'` for the data type of the generated column. Also what do you mean by *If the column were to be created with:... instead*? It's the same code as your initial code.

Comment: @forpas that's a bug in sqlite 3.31-3.36, the column type includes "generated always" at the end. It was fixed in 3.37

Comment: Also, edited my code, made a mistake in it, that's what the difference wasn't there

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, as usual, I find the answer right after asking it. According to sqlite documentation:

> The datatype and collating sequence of the generated column are determined only by the datatype and COLLATE clause on the column definition. The datatype and collating sequence of the GENERATED ALWAYS AS expression have no affect on the datatype and collating sequence of the column itself.

Which I assume means, that just as in other places, if the datatype is not specified, it is thought of as a blob.